# convert LinearLayout to GridLayout android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridlayout

I really need help I wanted an interface like this [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNKVG.png). I have done it with LinearLayout, but I wanted to do it with GridView, so please help me. I am fetching the pictures from the database.

**This is my activity java:**

```
 public class GestionImage {

    public static  void loadImageFromUr(Context context, String url, ImageView image) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(image) {
                    @Override
                    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                        super.setResource(resource);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java** Code here :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<CategorieEntity> listCategories;
    LinearLayout layoutBtn;
    ArrayList<LinearLayout> listlayoutBtnText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listCategories = new ArrayList<CategorieEntity>();
        CategorieEntity fruit = new CategorieEntity(1, "Fruit", "desc cate 1", "https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/280304/set-icone-frutta.png");
        CategorieEntity legume = new CategorieEntity(2, "Legumes", "desc 2", "https://icon-icons.com/icons2/53/PNG/256/fruits_vegetables_10762.png");
        listCategories.add(fruit);
        listCategories.add(legume);
        layoutBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutImageButton);
        listlayoutBtnText = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listCategories.size(); i++) {
            //imageCategories.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            ImageView imageCategories = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

            GestionImage.loadImageFromUr(getApplicationContext(), listCategories.get(i).getImageCategorie(), imageCategories);
            TextView libelleCategories = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            libelleCategories.setText(listCategories.get(i).getLibelleCategorie());
            LinearLayout layoutBtnText = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            layoutBtnText.addView(imageCategories);
            layoutBtnText.addView(libelleCategories);
            listlayoutBtnText.add(layoutBtnText);
            final int finalI = i;
            imageCategories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    long idCategorie = listCategories.get(finalI).getIdCategorie();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListSelonCategorie.class);
                    intent.putExtra("idCategories", idCategorie);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < listlayoutBtnText.size(); i++) {
            layoutBtn.addView(listlayoutBtnText.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

[image: you need to do some changes in your actitvity]

> Start with an empty activity. You will perform the following tasks to add the RecyclerView . All you need to do is copy and paste the code in each section. Later you can customize it to fit your needs.

- Add dependencies to gradle
- Add the xml layout files for the activity and for the grid cell
- Make the RecyclerView adapter
- Initialize the RecyclerView in your activity

  ## Add Dependecies Here

  **Make sure the following dependencies are in your app gradle.build file:**

---

`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'`

---

## Create activity layout$

Add the `RecyclerView` to your xml layout.

`activity_main.xml`

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvNumbers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

---

## Create grid cell layout

Each cell in our `RecyclerView` grid is only going to have a single `TextView`. Create a new layout resource file.

`recyclerview_item.xml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

       </LinearLayout>
```

---

## Create the adapter$

The `RecyclerView` needs an `adapter` to populate the views in each cell with your data. Create a new java file.

`MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java`

---

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String[] mData = new String[0];
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

// data is passed into the constructor
MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, String[] data) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mData = data;
}

// inflates the cell layout from xml when needed
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

// binds the data to the textview in each cell
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String animal = mData[position];
    holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
}

// total number of cells
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.length;
}


// stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView myTextView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

// convenience method for getting data at click position
String getItem(int id) {
    return mData[id];
}

// allows clicks events to be caught
void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
 }
```

---

## Note

Although not strictly necessary, I included the functionality for listening for click events on the cells. This was available in the old GridView and is a common need. You can remove this code if you don't need it.

---

## Initialize RecyclerView in Activity

Add the following code to your `main activity`.

`MainActivity.java`

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // data to populate the RecyclerView with
    String[] data = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"};

    // set up the RecyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvNumbers);
    int numberOfColumns = 6;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, data);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Log.i("TAG", "You clicked number " + adapter.getItem(position) + ", which is at cell position " + position);
       }
         }
```

---

## Notes

Notice that the activity implements the `ItemClickListener` that we defined in our adapter. This allows us to handle cell click events in `onItemClick`.

Comment: why you have recycler view inside relative layout? there should be only recyclerview. Same for the item view, only text view, try to avoid unnecessary nesting.